# history.pushstate not updating title

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser-history

I am using AJAX to load main content of the page. Using `history.pushstate(Object:State, String:Title, String:URL)` - I am able to update the URL in the address bar and navigate back in the history.

However the `title` parameter appears to have no effect. Neither does the window title change nor the title of the entries in the 'history list' (perhaps both of them are same anyway).

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**: `title` param is simply ignored in chrome. http://lists.whatwg.org/pipermail/whatwg-whatwg.org/2010-June/026827.html

Comment: I am work-around this simply by using: `document.title = "NEW_TITLE"` before a call to `history.pushstate` but why does it not work the way its supposed to?

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong, that's the way it works. The history API changes the URL and you have to do the rest, like change the documents contents, including the title.

Comment: then does it mean - the `title` param is a dummy?

Comment: No, the title param is not a dummy, it just does'nt change the documents title automagically, as those are just two different things with a similar name.

Comment: okay, but then what is the use of the `title` param?

Comment: It adds a title to the record in the windows history, it's not the document title.

Comment: Best description of the issue and two good answers are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324990/title-of-history-pushstate-is-unsupported-whats-a-good-alternative

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `title` parameter is not the window title.
It may be used as a title of the state but
some browsers like *Chrome* simply ignore it.

Comment: if title of the state - is the *string* i see in the history list (by pressing and holding the `Back` button in chrome - then well even that seems to be unaffected by `histroty.pushstate:title`

Comment: Some browsers  (such as FF) ignore the parameter, yes.

Comment: What is the intended use of the `title` param then - in the browsers that do support them?

Comment: As far as I can tell by the spec there is no intended use. It just says "The title is purely advisory. User agents might use the title in the user interface."

Comment: In reality, currently (see date of my comment) all browsers ignore the title parameter and do not use it for the title bar or history list. The intended use was to only update the history list – not the document title, but browser developers decided not to implement it this way, probably because it would be confusing if the history list showed something else than the document.title at that time. See http://lists.whatwg.org/htdig.cgi/whatwg-whatwg.org/2010-June/026827.html

Comment: @Blaise, In reality Safari and Opera supports it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26316325/632951 . **And this feature is importantly useful, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/26324990/632951** . Without this feature all the history entries will show the same title even when we replace pages with pushState.

Answer (score 4):

As @ujjwal-singh has already written in his answer the 2nd parameter `title` may be used as a label for the entry in the history but it is optional and the browser can ignore it and decide to use a different source for the title. The [note below bullet point 8 at chapter 5.5.2 of the HTML 5 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#history-1) states

> The `title` is purely advisory. User agents might use the title in the user interface.

This is how Chrome and Firefox work. Hence, the following code should lead to a consistent user experience among all major browsers

```
document.title = myTitle;
history.pushState( myState, myTitle, myURL );
```

This code also updates the title of the document and Chrome and Firefox are supposed to use this one.

However, it **does not work as expected and you will experience a weird off-by-one bug**. (This is at least true for FF up to version 45 and Chrome 51.) The problem is that the UI is not updated immediately but only after the JS call stack becomes empty. Hence, `pushState` will still use the old (out-dated) title, because the new title of the document is not yet applied to the DOM. On the next call of this code snippet `pushState` uses the previously changed title and so on.

If the user picks an item from the history, the user is mislead to a different page than the user expects, because the labels of each history entry and the actual destination of the history entry are out-of-sync by one.

However, this looks like a bug in Chrome and Firefox to me. Although the UI is only updated after JS terminates `pushState` should already use the new title. I have filed a bug report both to Chromium and Mozilla.

Comment: I have `window.history.pushState(myStateObject, myNewTitle, myNewURL); document.title = myNewTitle;` working in Firefox 72 in Jan 2020. I have no idea how it's never occurred to me before that a `document.title` can be reset live. Excellent heads up.

Answer (score 1):

I doesn't know why that works like that, but because of [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817740/history-pushstate-not-updating-title#comment105846503_38830794) of Rounin which are next:

> I have window.history.pushState(myStateObject, myNewTitle, myNewURL); document.title = myNewTitle; working in Firefox 72 in Jan
> 2020. I have no idea how it's never occurred to me before that a document.title can be reset live. Excellent heads up.

I've suddenly found that in Firefox 91.0b9 you have to put pushState firstly, and secondly you have to change title. And then history manager in Ff 91.0b9 changing exact page that pushed state and not simular closer page with slightly different uri. In my case if document.title changed first, history management thing changes last two records with simular links of the site.

For example if some /page will be changed to /page/2, and you change title and then will make pushState, then both records titles will be changed to that one that you specified in document title or may be it's related to title in pushState. So when document.title called secondly it is works normally

Example (works):

```
window.history.pushState(myStateObject, myNewTitle, myNewURL);
document.title = myNewTitle;
```

And not like it is probably suppose to be (not works):

```
document.title = myNewTitle;
window.history.pushState(myStateObject, myNewTitle, myNewURL);
```

Thank you to the Rounin!