# How to set "default" value for history.pushState and replaceState?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, cross-browser, html5-history

For browsers that use the `title` param, what value should we use to tell the browser to use its default?

In Safari <sup><sub>5.1.7 (7534.57.2)</sub></sup>, if I put `null` or `undefined` as the `title` param, it uses the browser default:

[image]

However, Opera <sup><sub>12.16</sub></sup> uses the string `"null"` and `"undefined"` respectively:

[image]

What's supposed to be the "correct" behavior?

On Opera, how can we set to "default" if `"null"` and `"undefined"` doesn't work?

([MDN's `History` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) doesn't seem to have much info regarding the allowed values for `History.pushState`/`replaceState`'s parameters.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a specific way of setting it to a default title, but a safe way which should work in all browsers is setting the title to the `location.href`

```
document.title = location.href;
```

Comment: Browsers may display title in other ways than simply using the `location.href`. E.g. a customization which prepends `location.href` with a value or simply showing only the domain and not the path.

Comment: Indeed, but I don't know of any way to set it to the "default" one