# Is History API consistent across modern browsers?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, single-page-application, history.js, html5-history

History API is now [supported in every popular browser](http://caniuse.com/#search=history). It seems there's no need for hash fallbacks, `_escaped_fragment_` tricks or [other workarounds](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/wiki/Intelligent-State-Handling) anymore. Cool libraries from 2013 like [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/) seem useless now. But there are some things where I'm not sure - for example [title handling seems tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324990/title-of-history-pushstate-is-unsupported-whats-a-good-alternative) beacuse apparently `title` argument in `pushState` doesn't do anything.

My question is, can I actually rely on the History API to behave consistently across browsers, or do I still need some browser-specific code? This also means: do I need integration tests running in different browsers to test my code then? And if there are inconsistencies, what are they? (Note I'm interested only in *modern* browsers, so no IE<11).

Maybe someone who implemented routing for a big SPA could share their experience?

Comment: "I'm not interested only in modern browsers, so no IE<11" - there seems to be an extra not?

Comment: No browser supports and no browser will support the title argument to `pushState`/`replaceState`, it's too late now. You can just always pass an empty string there, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4):

*Note: This is not a complete answer so I'm not expecting a bounty but it still answers some concerns so I decided to put it as an answer*

There are still some differences as with most APIs (you won't believe how inconsistent classList is between browsers); the question is mostly how severe they are.

`pushState` is most commonly used in SPAs and they seem to ignore the object parameter and mostly handle the URL. This means bugs related to state object handling may be less "visible" to the general public.

The only issue I've recently found that influenced what I was doing is that in IE & Edge (even 14) `history.state` is a getter so it gets a fresh object instance on every access. This means you can't cache the state object and compare it to `history.state` to see if a new one was pushed. Here's the bug report: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/944050/

Also, note that no browser supports setting title via `pushState` and no one ever will, it's too late. If a browser started supporting that, `pushState`-using sites would suddenly clear all titles in browser history because code is passing empty strings there. You just have to accept that the second parameter is useless.

Comment: You said you're not expecting the bounty, but there is no answer I could mark as accepted, so according to SO bounty rules you will probably get it anyway. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can see all the supported browsers by history lib: https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/#browsers-tested-and-working-in

And buglist solved by this lib, from the same page:

> - HTML5 Browsers
>
>   - Chrome 8 sometimes does not contain the correct state data when traversing back to the initial state
>   - Safari 5, Safari iOS 4 and Firefox 3 and 4 do not fire the `onhashchange` event when the page is loaded with a hash
>   - Safari 5 and Safari iOS 4 do not fire the `onpopstate` event when the hash has changed unlike the other browsers
>   - Safari 5 and Safari iOS 4 fail to return to the correct state once a hash is replaced by a `replaceState` call / [bug report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=56249)
>   - Safari 5 and Safari iOS 4 sometimes fail to apply the state change under busy conditions / [bug report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42940)
>   - Google Chrome 8,9,10 and Firefox 4 prior to the RC will always fire `onpopstate` once the page has loaded / [change recommendation](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/03/history-api-changes-in-firefox-4/)
>   - Safari iOS 4.0, 4.1, 4.2 have a working HTML5 History API - although the actual back buttons of the browsers do not work, therefore we treat them as HTML4 browsers
>   - None of the HTML5 browsers actually utilise the `title` argument to the `pushState` and `replaceState` calls
> - HTML4 Browsers
>
>   - Old browsers like MSIE 6,7 and Firefox 2 do not have a `onhashchange` event
>   - MSIE 6 and 7 sometimes do not apply a hash even it was told to (requiring a second call to the apply function)
>   - Non-Opera HTML4 browsers sometimes do not apply the hash when the hash is not `urlencoded`
> - All Browsers
>
>   - State data and titles do not persist once the site is left and then returned (includes page refreshes)
>   - State titles are never applied to the `document.title`

This might tell you something about existing differences.

Comment: All the bug descriptions there are quite old.

Comment: @Artur, thank you for the bug list. It's good but note the project is quite old. I'm still not sure if this necessarily means "no more bugs in browsers since 2013".

Answer (score 0):

There were some issues with History API in Androids before 4 version, but generally it work well across all main browsers.

Comment: Vague answer of the year goes to...   :P